# css background image is messing up the body background color

Tags: html, css

The background for the whole page should be #111111. My navbar with a repeating background seems to change the color of the background that is under the navbar and above. I don't know what I am missing here

This is what I am getting:
[image]

This is what it should look like:

[image]

/*index.html*/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SomeWhere | Home</title>
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container" >
  <header>
   <nav class="topnav">

   </nav> 
  </header> 

  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

/*style.css*/

```html
/* CSS Document */
body{
 background-color: #111111;
}
#container{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #111111;
 color: #ffffff;
 
}

nav.topnav{
  margin: 0;
  top: 138px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
  background: #111111 url(../imgs/nvbck.png) repeat;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a link to your page or share the png file? Cannot reproduce the issue with above code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqgeOB

    nav.topnav is only 54px tall and doesn't seem to affect the rest of the page.

Comment: nvbck.png is at https://ibb.co/gs6M0b. This should be fine, Daniel Sixl tried it and he is not getting the same issue. Can't for the life of me figure out what I am getting this at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok when I replicate it:
https://jsfiddle.net/Sixtus78/97r4mm39/

```css
/* CSS Document */

body{
 background-color: #111111;
}

.container{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #111111;
 color: #ffffff;
 
}

nav.topnav{
  margin: 0;
  top: 138px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
  background: #111111 url(http://cdn.backgroundhost.com/backgrounds/subtlepatterns/bo_play_pattern.png) repeat;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <header>
   <nav class="topnav">
        Nav
   </nav> 
  </header> 
  <div class="hero">
    Hero
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   Content
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why I am getting this issue on my end. I have tried this in firefox and google and I have these issue.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what browser are you using?  I went back and tested it again with firefox, edge, and  and I am not getting the issue. I reset chrome completely and still getting this anomaly.

Comment: I checked in Firefox v55.0.3 and Chrome v61.0.3163.100

Comment: You have this issue when opening my jsfiddle?

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with your browser ;)

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I appreciate it.

Comment: You have a container with class: 
<div class="container" ></div> 
But you're styling a container with id:
 #container{}
Not related though.

Answer (score 0):

After testing out several other browsers and seeing that this only happening in chrome, I reset chrome to default and restarted chrome without any results. I decided to completely uninstall chrome and do a fresh installation. This apparently fixed the issue I was having.